# No source code available error when using string array

Tags: c++

I use windows 7 and VS2010.
I want to use string array：

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

string Value[8] = {"0"} ;

int Value_no = 0;

/*.....*/    

void CControllerDlg::HandlePacket(char *pkt, int len)
{   
    Value[Value_no] = pkt;  
    Value_no += 1;  
}
```

But when I run single step debug. Error occurs at `string Value[8] = {"0"} ;`

Error:

[image: Error]

Comment: Please post the error as text, not as an image

Comment: Does it help if you put `std::string` instead of just `string`? Either way there seems to be something wrong with how your project is set up if that's your error message.

Comment: Null pointers are not valid initialisers for `std::string`, and you have seven of them. Only the first array element has a valid initialiser.

Comment: The first four lines of that code can't possibly compile, much less be debugged. There is no `string` type in the standard library without `std` namespace qualification, and since you're not qualifying `std` in any form, that code can't compile. So, forget the "my code is like..." and try "my code *is*..." so we can actually see the *real* problem.

Comment: @ molbdnilo How to correct it?

Comment: `std::string` has a default constructor which initializes it with an empty (but valid) string. So, it would be even better to drop the array initialization.

Comment: @ Scheff Thx, your suggestion worked.

Comment: Another option: `std::string Value[] = { "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0" };` If you want to get the array size (e.g. for loop limit) it could be done by `const size_t nValues = sizeof Value / sizeof *Value;` This is a trick which allows to add initializers (if more capacity is needed) without breaking the rest of code.

Comment: @Bill That depends on what "correct" is. Eight `"0"`s, eight empty strings, or one `"0"` and seven empty strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made string array of 8 elements and you only described one. Try declaring other values, from 0 to 7.